# Classe QrCode funcionando somente dentro de arquivo de rotas

Tags: php, laravel, qrcode

Dentro do arquivo de rotas o seguinte código funciona normalmente:

```
QrCode::format('png')
      ->size(400)
      ->color(0,0,0,100)
      ->backgroundColor(255,255,255,0)
      ->margin(20)
      ->generate('google.com', public_path('images\qrcode7.png'));
```

Mas ao tentar executar dentro do arquivo `RegisterController` o mesmo comando, aparece o erro:

> `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\QrCode' not found`

Alguma sugestão de como resolver? Dentro do arquivo de rotas eu não importei nada, e dentro do `controller` também não achei nenhum arquivo que eu importando funcionou.

A biblioteca que estou usando é a [Simple QrCode](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

incluindo

```
use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Generator;
```

e usando dessa maneira:

```
(new Generator)->format('png')->size(400)->color(0,0,0,100)->backgroundColor(255,255,255,0)->margin(20)->generate('google.com', public_path('images\qrcode7.png'));
```

Funcionou normalmente, só não entendi o porquê dele funcionar dentro do arquivo de rotas daquele maneira